# How to set an incrementing ID property to a class' collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have some nested objects arranged like this:

- Process

  - Persons
  - Workflows

    - Tasks

So you have one Process.  Then multiple Persons can be added to and multiple WorkFlows can be added Process as well.  Multiple Tasks can be added to each WorkFlow but I need a way to tie which Person is doing each task.  I basically need a way that for each Person added to the Process it, in it's constructor, assigns a Person.ID property that can then be assigned into each Task's PersonID property...

```
Dim myProcess as New Process()

Dim myPerson as New Process.Person()

myProcess.AddPerson(myPerson)

Dim myWorkFlow as New Process.WorkFlow()

Dim myTask as New Process.WorkFlow.Task()

myTask.PersonID = myPerson.ID '<--- AutoID was populated as soon as myPerson was created

myWorkFlow.AddTask(myTask)

myProcess.AddWorkFlow(myWorkFlow)
```

**Here's a PasteBin of some pseudo-code: http://pastebin.com/0r9rnUjz**

Comment: Does it need to be auto incrementing or just unique? If the latter then you could just use a GUID.

Comment: Do these need to be persisted? Is it OK for these to reset if the application restarts?

Comment: @Chris, yes I thought about that but there is a chance that they need to be integers.

Comment: @Oded, no they don't need to persist.  Just for the life of the Process object.

Comment: @EdenMachine, Integers are 32 bit objects and GUIDs are 128 bits objects, essentially 4 Integers. Does you *chance* allow for that? Your life will be a lot easier if so.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, yes, I definitely see your point and I agree.  I only have so much control over certain aspects of the application though.  Some are legacy and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Guid instead like Chris Haas suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some shared variable in your Person class so that for each new instance created, it will get a new id from that counter, as in the example below.

```
Public Class Person
    Private incrementedID As Integer = 0
    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.incrementedID
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Shared nextId As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New()
        Me.incrementedID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(nextId)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: FYI - your code didn't work because the nextId increment would get reset every time a new Person would get instantiated inside the Process.

Comment: No, it won't get reset. It's a `Shared` property, so it lives as long as the process (or the AppDomain) lives.

Comment: Ahh - I guess I missed the shared part of that.  I'll try it again.